# How to calculate point values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written code to calculate the values like integer values.

```
function add_number(inp) {
    var tr = inp.parentNode.parentNode;
    var first_number = parseInt(tr.querySelector('[data-id="qty"]').value);
    var second_number = parseInt(tr.querySelector('[data-id="amtper"]').value);

    var result = first_number * second_number;
    tr.querySelector('[data-id="total"]').value = result ? result : '';
}
```

By the above code U am able to calculate only round values, if I calculate the values 10.60*10 = 106, (the value should be displayed). But I am getting 100.

How to calculate point values?

Comment: Use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt()` parses only integer values without decimal value.

Use `parseFloat()` instead.

```
var first_number = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('[data-id="qty"]').value);
var second_number = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('[data-id="amtper"]').value);
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I calculate the values 10.60*10 = 106, (the value should be
>   displayed). But I am getting 100

Because when you do parseInt, it returns an Intger without any decimal value.

Use `parseFloat` instead, Replace

```
var first_number = parseInt(tr.querySelector('[data-id="qty"]').value);
var second_number = parseInt(tr.querySelector('[data-id="amtper"]').value);
```

with

```
var first_number = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('[data-id="qty"]').value);
var second_number = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('[data-id="amtper"]').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

parseInt will convert 10.60 to 10 before the multiplication. You need to use parseFloat instead. In case you expect an integer or a number with fixed number digits after the decimal point, you can use the precision parameter to set it.

```
function add_number(inp, precision) {
    precision = typeof precision !== "number"? 0: precision;
    var tr = inp.parentNode.parentNode;
    var first_number = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('[data-id="qty"]').value);
    var second_number = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('[data-id="amtper"]').value);

    var result = (first_number * second_number).toFixed(precision);
    tr.querySelector('[data-id="total"]').value = result ? result : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)? See this:

```js
function add_number(inp) {
    var tr = inp.parentNode.parentNode;
    var first_number = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('[data-id="qty"]').value);
    var second_number = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('[data-id="amtper"]').value);

    var result = first_number * second_number;
    tr.querySelector('[data-id="total"]').value = result ? result : '';
}

add_number(document.getElementById("inp"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  QTY: <input data-id="qty" value="100"><br>
  AMTPER: <input data-id="amtper" value="1.06">
  <div>
    <div id="inp"></div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  Total, filled by JS:
  <input data-id="total">
</div>
```